# How come Draq5 stains cytoplasm and membranes under confocal

Tags: imaging

Just an imaging question on the back of my head.
For nuclear counter stain, Draq5 has been an excellent choice for many people over many years. And I too love it.

The working principle of Draq5 is the nuclear dye Draq5 binds to doubles strand DNA, especially d-A and d-T. That is to say it is very specific to stain nucleus DNA, minimal binding to mitochondria DNA, and no binding to RNA. It is also a very good live cell permeant dye.

In practice, we use it to stain cell nucleus and then perform image analysis, the primary objective in image analysis is identification of the cell object, usually through nucleus staining. No problem, Draq5 does this perfectly, I can see my image crispy clear.

Next, it comes to the estimation of the entire cell, that is to find cell membrane boundaries. A huge advantage of Draq 5 is it also stain cytoplasm and cell membrane weakly, allowing the accurate detection of cell boundaries. Comparing this to Hoechst dye, which also stain nucleus and weakly cytoplasm only for estimation of cell boundaries. This is unlikely a Draq5 non-specific binding, since data from resistant cancer cells that have membrane drug pumps still retain Draq5 very well.

I'm not a chemist so that one thing in the back of my head is:
Why does Draq5 bind cytoplasm and outlines cell membranes that well? Given it is highly specific to bind A/T in double strand DNA grooves. Presumably the dye is binding to its cytoplasm target and membrane target via different mechanisms. Can someone explain that?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please provide more details and tell us what you already know (this provides context for answers and helps demonstrate that you have done the expected prior research). In particular, if you are seeing an unexpected pattern of staining it would be helpful to include images showing 1) the expected pattern (e.g. from prior research published using this dye — make sure you include reference information and links for these) and 2) what you are seeing (including details of the cells type/tissue, growth, and staining). ——— Off-hand I would guess that you are seeing an artifact.

Comment: Unsure if question ultimately seeks practical advise. If so: Ensure application to living cells and avoid fixing and permeabilization. If problem persists: do saturation curve with concentrations spanning some orders of magnitude.

Comment: Sorry, I was just lost in my thoughts and posted the half baked idea. Here I have updated my thinking. @tsttst, the staining of cytoplasm and cell membrane happens within its working range, this is actually the advantage of Draq5. In my own experiment Draq5 intensity far from saturation, I can see it over the range set by 16 bit camera, intensity is about the same as my TMRE.